# I can't find my uploaded files in Dropbox

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I'm working on uploading some countries' admin data to my Dropbox app. Here below is my code that does that:

```
# importing the required libraries
import dropbox, sys, os
import requests

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'qie********'
app_secret = 'qom**********'

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('YYPRp-*******************_JzclLe-***************-3Js')

# verify if the account is connected
dbx.users_get_current_account()

#find all the folders present
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('').entries:
    print(entry.name)
    

# creating a path to where all the data to be uploaded is
root_dir = "H:/WORK/Upwork/Project 7 - Python School Data Analysis/Planning and Costing Model/Updated Script/Extracted" 

print ("Attempting to upload...")


z = 1
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    # the first dir is the root dir itself so we skip it
    if z == 1:
        z = z + 1
        continue
    # uploading contents of the file path
    elif z > 15:
        # split the path to get the country, which is the very last item after split (-1)
        split_dir = dir.split('\\')
        folder_name = split_dir[-1] # country name
        # creating a new folder in my Dropbox for each country
        country_name = dbx.files_create_folder('/Data/'+ folder_name)
        dropbox_folder = country_name.path_display #obtaining the name of the folder
        folder_split = dropbox_folder.split('/') # splitting the path to get root folder and created folder
        folder_created = folder_split[-1] #created/country folder
        dest_path = os.path.join('/Data/', folder_created) #joining the two to make a full path
        print(dest_path)
        # looping through the files in each of the country's folder
        for file in files:
            try:
                # getting the path for each of the file in the folder
                file_path = os.path.join(dir, file)
                print(f'Uploading to {folder_name} in Dropbox')
                f = open(file_path, 'rb')
                connect = '/' # will be used to separate the destination path and the file
                # this is where the file will be saved
                d_path = os.path.join(dest_path, connect, file)
                dbx.files_upload(f.read(), d_path, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
                print(dest_path)
                print(file_path)
                print(dir)
                print('\n')
                
            except Exception as err:
                print("Error!", file, err)
    z = z + 1
```

The code runs successfully with no errors. Here is how it looks at the console:

[image]

It successfully creates the folders for each of the countries. Note that in my countries' folders, it has several files (max of 15). When I visit my dropbox app, the folders are there but nothing is inside the folders. There are completely not files, I receive the message notification that says:

> This Folder is Empty

See below the images:

With folders created
[image]

One of the countries, with no files:
[image]

I have given it over an hour but nothing changes. Also note that I configured all permissions necessary for writing files and folders. Could there be something I may have done wrong? I will appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Comment: A few things to check: a) print out `d_path` to make sure you're specifying the path you expect to, b) print out the result of the `files_upload` call (it should contain the metadata of the uploaded file), c) make sure you're using an access token for the app with access type that you expect, and d) make sure you're using an access token connected to the account that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Greg. The issue was actually in the `d_path` which wasn't a complete path. I have rectified it and everything seems okay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from Greg, I was able to find where the issue was. The files_upload class functions expects a working path as part of its parameters. The path provided could not be found in the App and so I added the following to make it work: `d_path = dest_path+d_path`

Here is the full working code:

```
# importing the required libraries
import dropbox, sys, os
import requests

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
app_key = 'qie********'
app_secret = 'qom**********'

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('YYPRp-*******************_JzclLe-***************-3Js')

# verify if the account is connected
dbx.users_get_current_account()

#find all the folders present
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder('').entries:
    print(entry.name)
    

# creating a path to where all the data to be uploaded is
root_dir = "H:/WORK/Upwork/Project 7 - Python School Data Analysis/Planning and Costing Model/Updated Script/Extracted" 

print ("Attempting to upload...")


z = 1
for dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    # the first dir is the root dir itself so we skip it
    if z == 1:
        z = z + 1
        continue
    # uploading contents of the file path
    elif z > 15:
        # split the path to get the country, which is the very last item after split (-1)
        split_dir = dir.split('\\')
        folder_name = split_dir[-1] # country name
        # creating a new folder in my Dropbox for each country
        country_name = dbx.files_create_folder('/Data/'+ folder_name)
        dropbox_folder = country_name.path_display #obtaining the name of the folder
        folder_split = dropbox_folder.split('/') # splitting the path to get root folder and created folder
        folder_created = folder_split[-1] #created/country folder
        dest_path = os.path.join('/Data/', folder_created) #joining the two to make a full path
        print(dest_path)
        # looping through the files in each of the country's folder
        for file in files:
            try:
                # getting the path for each of the file in the folder
                file_path = os.path.join(dir, file)
                print(f'Uploading to {folder_name} in Dropbox')
                f = open(file_path, 'rb')
                connect = '/' # will be used to separate the destination path and the file
                # this is where the file will be saved
                d_path = os.path.join(dest_path, connect, file)
                d_path = dest_path+d_path
                dbx.files_upload(f.read(), d_path, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
                print(dest_path)
                print(file_path)
                print(dir)
                print('\n')
                
            except Exception as err:
                print("Error!", file, err)
    z = z + 1
```